# How trigger programmatically ui-sref element in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have these navigation buttons inside view:

```
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step1"><span>STEP1</span></a>
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step2"><span>STEP2</span></a>
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step3"><span>STEP3</span></a>
</div>
```

When DOM is loaded I want this row:

```
<a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step1"><span>STEP1</span></a>
```

Triggered programmatically (i.e make imitation of pressing the button ).

What is the elegant way to make it in angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of pressing button, you can use `$state.go('.step1')` in the controller, so it will call the when the controller is first load

use `$state.go('.step1')` in the controller.

**OR** use like this,

```
<div id="status-buttons" class="text-center" ng-init="initScope()">
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step1"><span>STEP1</span></a>
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step2"><span>STEP2</span></a>
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".step3"><span>STEP3</span></a>
</div>
```

in controller,

```
$scope.initScope = function() {
    $state.go('.step1');
}
```

Comment: I need the anchor tag to be marked as selected it can be marked only when it pressed by user or progrommatically